# Excluding tuples based on maximum condition

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I have been trying to answer to solve this SQL Query problem, but got no success. The problem is the following:

**PROBLEM:**

*Given 4 tables, **PRODUCTS**, **REPAIRS**, **OWNERS** and **MALFUNCTION**, for each product Brand and Model display the type of malfunction which have been repaired more times.*

The tables have the following fields:

```
PRODUCTS: *Series_num, Brand, Model, Year, Code_Owner
OWNERS: *Code_Owner, Name, Surname, Street, Civic, City, (u)Phone
MALFUNCTIONS: *Malf_code, Desc
REPAIRS: *Series_num, *Malf_code, *Repair_Date, Price

* <- Primary key
(u) <- Unique attribute
```

The expected result, given this example of data:

```
| MODEL  |  BRAND   |  MALF_CODE  | NUMBER OF REPAIRS|
|----------------------------------------------------|
|   1    |  BRAND1  |      1      |        20        |
|   1    |  BRAND1  |      2      |        10        |
|   2    |  BRAND1  |      1      |         1        |
|   2    |  BRAND1  |      2      |         1        |
|   1    |  BRAND2  |      1      |        10        |
|   1    |  BRAND2  |      2      |        11        |
```

Should be:

```
| MODEL  |  BRAND   |  MALF_CODE  | NUMBER OF REPAIRS|
|----------------------------------------------------|
|   1    |  BRAND1  |      1      |        20        |
|   2    |  BRAND1  |      1      |         1        |
|   1    |  BRAND2  |      2      |        11        |
```

*Note that BRAND1, MODEL:2 has the same number of repairs for two different types of malfunction, so one of the rows can be ignored or both of them can be shown (it does not matter)*

---

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

To get the first table, I used a simple JOIN query:

```sql
SELECT A.MODEL, A.BRAND, R.MALF_CODE, COUNT(*) AS N_REP
FROM REPAIRS R LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS A ON A.SERIES_NUM = R.SERIES_NUM
GROUP BY A.MODEL, A.BRAND, R.MALF_CODE;
```

Then I tried to get the second table thanks to *MAX()* function:

```sql
SELECT A.MODEL, A.BRAND, R.MALF_CODE, COUNT(*) AS N_REP
FROM REPAIRS R LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS A ON A.SERIES_NUM = R.SERIES_NUM
GROUP BY A.MODEL, A.BRAND, R.MALF_CODE
HAVING COUNT(*) IN(
    SELECT MAX(R.MALF_CODE)
    FROM REPAIRS R LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS A ON A.SERIES_NUM = R.SERIES_NUM
    GROUP BY A.MODEL, A.BRAND, R.MALF_CODE
    ORDER BY A.BRAND, R.MALF_CODE);
```

But this throws me the following error:

`[42000][907] ORA-00907: Missing closing Parenthesis`

It seems I can't find the error.
I hope I've been clear enough. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm aware of RANK functions and such, but never heard of Partitions. So a solution without them is highly appreciated but not mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want the row with the most repairs for each model/brand combination.  If so, window functions are one method:

```
SELECT MODEL, BRAND, MALF_CODE, N_REP
FROM (SELECT P.MODEL, P.BRAND, R.MALF_CODE, COUNT(*) AS N_REP,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.MODEL, P.BRAND ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, R.MALF_CODE) as SEQNUM
      FROM REPAIRS R LEFT JOIN
           PRODUCTS P
           ON P.SERIES_NUM = R.SERIES_NUM
      GROUP BY P.MODEL, P.BRAND, R.MALF_CODE
     ) MB
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Your example works perfectly. However I've not studied partition, so if you have another example in mind can you give me a tip on how to write the query? I do not want to bother you. I will read some documentation about partition however.